# How to add clientOption on existing ClientConn?

Tags: go, oauth, grpc

I'm writing gRPC client application with go language.

Every ClientConn has JWT token, now I have some problem during applying caching/reusing ClientConn with various JWT token now.

Previously I have created ClientConn for every time with new JWT token like below:

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial(endpoint, WithPerRPCCredentials(oauth.NewOauthAccess(token))
```

But in my application, token is changed every time. But I can't find a way to reuse existing ClientConn with only applying new token.

Is there a way to replacing specific DialOption (or replacing JWT token) with existing ClientConn?

Or is this a best way to inject `Authorization` metadata into the context for every gRPC call?

Comment: The implementation of the PerRpcCredentials object should be refreshing the access token by itself, if necessary. See https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/f313ade84ce22334b1411af48361ab7fcf1c91df/credentials/credentials.go#L38. It seems odd to need to tear down and recreate clientconns only refresh these tokens. I'm not sure exactly where it is, but I think there should be a PerRPCCredentials API that handles refreshing, which I'm guessing is what you'd want here.

Answer (score 0):

As @apolcyn mentioned, PerRpcCredentials implementations usually take care of refreshing the access token.

If you have a JWT token, you could also look into using [NewJWTAccessFromFile](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/oauth#NewJWTAccessFromFile) or [NewJWTAccessFromKey](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/oauth#NewJWTAccessFromKey).

In any case if your token source can change and you still want to be able to use the same `ClientConn`, you could use a `CallOption` to specify your credentials during every RPC that you make instead of specifying it as a `DialOption` during the creation of your `ClientConn`. This is the callOption of interest for you: https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#PerRPCCredentials

Another option to inject arbitrary metadata into every gRPC call is to use client side interceptors. See `WithUnaryInterceptor` or `WithStreamInterceptor` dialOptions.

Hope this helps.